# Magento Collection: can we set a query /w joins and all as collection/resource?

Tags: adminhtml, collection, resource-model

Magento Collection: can we set a query /w joins and all as collection/resource?

We are creating a custom grid. And accessing a data collection query from different angles. In Model/Resource we *normally* can set something like

```
class Class_Module_Model_Preorders extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('module/table');
    }
}
```

In our grid.php we access and join several tables to a collection. The problem is that we cannot access it from everywhere. So my question would be

**Question**: How can make the query below a resource collection that we can access from anywhere?

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{

    // Base collection is preorder
    $collection = Mage::getModel('somemodule/table')->getCollection();
    // Pre orders only
    $collection->getSelect()->where("main_table.is_preorder = 1");
    // Add Order item table to get orderitem data + order id
    // Filter by parent_item_id IS NOT NULL to get child only (parent link is then missing: have to join again to get the data)
    $collection->join(array('soi' =>'sales/order_item'), 'main_table.order_item_id = soi.item_id AND soi.parent_item_id IS NOT NULL', array('item_id', 'order_id', 'parent_item_id','sku' , 'name', 'qty_ordered'));
```